# disable .slice position parameter starting at beginning of array if the absolute value if greater than the array length

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

the mongodb documentation here (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) says that:

> If negative, $slice determines the starting position from the end of the array. If the absolute value of the  is greater than the number of elements, the starting position is the start of the array.

Is there any way to disable this behaviour?

My motivation for this is as follows: 
I am building a messaging app and want to build pagination into retrieving the messages. Currently, I load 25 messages at a time **starting from the end of the array**. The user can then load 25 more messages by fetching the next page. I am using the .slice() function to load 25 messages at a time from the end of the array. Here's my code:

```
Conversation.findOne({ id: chatId})
 .select('name message timeCreated')
 .slice('messages', [-25 * page, 25])
 .exec(function (err, result) {
  // do stuff with result
})
```

However, with this approach, once I reach the beginning of the array (since I am loading messages from the end of the array), the slice command gets the first 25 messages over and over again because of the default behaviour with respect to the position parameter.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: sorry, the message field should actually be messages, because it is an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the aggregation pipeline to do this as follows:

```
Models.Participant.aggregate([
                { '$match': { 'id': chatId, 'user_ids': _id } },
                {
                    '$project': {
                        'messages': {
                            '$cond': {
                                if: { '$gte': [(25 * page) - 25, { '$size': '$conversation.messages' }] },
                                then: [],
                                else: {
                                    '$slice': ['$conversation.messages', -25 * page,
                                        {
                                            '$cond': {
                                                if: { '$gte': [{ '$size': '$conversation.messages' }, page * 25] },
                                                then: 25,
                                                else: { '$subtract': [{ '$size': '$conversation.messages' }, ((page - 1) * 25)] }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]).exec(async function (err, result) {...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query to get the 25 messages .

```
Conversation.find({id : chatId} )
     .select('name message timeCreated')    
     .exec(function(err, foundRecord) {
     if (err || !scores) {
         throw err;
     } else {
         startingIndex = page*25;
         message = [];
         for(var i = startingIndex; i < startingIndex + 25 ; i++){
          message.push(foundRecord.message[i]);
         }
         foundRecord.message = message;
         // do something cool
     }
});
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, i didn't explain it too well in my question. Conversation holds one conversation, and several messages. So I need to sort by messages, which is actually an array. .sort will only sort the documents in a collection, not the elements of an array itself

Comment: Okk got it . Will get back to you with solution .

Comment: Thanks, but I think but looping through the result after querying the DB doesn't seem like a very good solution... I figured out how to do it with the aggregation pipeline. Still, thanks for your help!